# Ajax Request Failing, s is undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the below jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#ajaxButton').click(function ()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/getsomestring',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data)
            {
                alert('test');
            }
        });
    });
})
```

On the button click, I want to do an AJAX call.  On my server-side, I do have an action method `GetSomeString()`, which returns a string.  I'm just testing to make sure the AJAX request is successful by a simple `alert()`.  But for some reason, Firebug is giving me the error:

> **s is undefined**

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**:

In Firebug, the error is actually referenced in the **jquery-1.5.1-vsdocs.js** script (like 7320).  Obviously I didn't write that code, nor do I think that's the problem.  I only get this error when I use my `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: Could you let us know which line is causing that error? There are no variables `s` in your script, so this is likely an error elsewhere, or a syntax error.

Comment: @JesseFulton Good point, and thanks for asking that.  Check out my edit.  It's actually a jquery file that is getting referenced with the error.

Comment: Your code works (http://jsfiddle.net/jessefulton/hcJrd/) - 99% chance it's a syntax error elsewhere in your script.

Comment: @JesseFulton Ok, I see that in jsFiddle.  Thanks for proving that.  But where the error is, that's not *my* script.  That's a jQuery script!  What could be causing that??  And also, the above code is the extent of my script.  That's all there is to it, just that code.

Comment: @JesseFulton Isn't the "vsdoc" file supposed to just be for intellisense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually with the **jquery-1.5.1-vsdocs.js** JavaScript file.  For some reason, it was throwing the above error in the *$.ajax()* call.  Once I took the script reference out, and it didn't get loaded the **AJAX** request worked.

*Any ideas or theories as to why this caused the issue would be much appreciated.*  But the removal of it fixed the code.

Comment: I wasn't aware of a 'vsdocs' version/flavor of jQuery. Is it like a fork or something?

Comment: I would've assumed a production script wouldn't have those errors :). The only thing I can think of is that another script on the page which is causing conflicts (and *might* be resolved by using http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: @RobertoLinares Actually it is a *js* file that is part of an ASP.NET MVC file for their scripts.  From reading up on it, it's soley for Intellisense.  Why code was called in **that** script file, is beyond me.